# Add fulltext index with PostgreSQL in Laravel 4 Migrations

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to add a full-text index to a table in my migrations, but I cant get it working. the code I've tried dosen't error and even works when run in my SQL manager, but does not create an index when I call migrate command.

The commands below are the file thats last in the list to be run.

Ive tried the following, commented and uncommented:

```
public function up()
{
    //DB::raw('create index qsearch on questions (question)');
    DB::raw('CREATE INDEX question_fulltext_idx ON questions USING gin(to_tsvector("english", question))');
}
```

The table is `questions`, the column is `question`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the PostgreSQL server error log, after enabling at least `log_statement = 'ddl'`, preferably `log_statement = 'all'`. See what your framework is actually running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I was using the wrong quotes, this now works:

```
DB::statement("CREATE INDEX question_fulltext_idx ON questions USING gin(to_tsvector('english', question))");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `CREATE INDEX ..` query itself. But you're not actually running the query agains the database.

This "creates" a raw query:

```
DB::raw('CREATE INDEX question_fulltext_idx ON questions USING gin(to_tsvector("english", question))');
```

The newly created raw query would then be used inside another query.

This actually runs your statement against the database:

```
DB::statement('CREATE INDEX question_fulltext_idx ON questions USING gin(to_tsvector("english", question))');
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Hmmm, I get this error now: 

`[ErrorException]                                                                                                                                     
  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection' does not have a method 'statment'`

Comment: you misspelled `statment` you need to use `DB::statement`. Notice the e.

Comment: Yep. That's postgres telling you there's a problem in your statement. I don't know about that. Maybe try to use the statement in postgres directly before running the query with laravel

Comment: Yeah it works in PostgreSQL directly like I said. Just not via Laravel.